# Access to iFrame blocked

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension, and I want it to **access the elements within an iFrame** whose source is in another domain. I tried doing it within my Content Script in which I'm doing all the other stuff, but it got **blocked because of the different domain**. Is there any way I can bypass it, maybe running the script from the main extension and not from a content script?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Took me some time to try it out, but it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because of XSS protection. You can if you can get permission from the website you are loading into your iframe. If you cannot then I am sorry you have to come up with a different approach.